Is there an app that can ensure certain other apps stay running?
I remember elementary OS had(?) something like this, called cerbere, where you just needed to add an app to the list and it would ensure it's restarted if it crashes.
Is there anything like this around today? I'd like to keep Nextcloud client running (it seems to crash randomly, and sometimes doesn't start with the system like It's supposed to, and I don't have the time to keep looking out for that).

cerbere was for catching all running pantheon apps That might be a bit overkill of only for nextcloud client; if only for that I would use a systemd unit :) someone already made you one: https://blog.svedr.in/posts/running-the-nextcloud-client-under-systemd/ :)
